# comparing date value between two array

Tags: php, arrays, date

so, I have some dates in two arrays:

```
$old_1 = array(
    array(
                'start_date' => '2014-09-06',
                'end_date' => ' 2014-09-07'
            ),
            array(
                'start_date' => '2014-09-26',
                'end_date' => '2014-09-28'
            ),
            array(
                'start_date' => '2014-09-29',
                'end_date' => '2014-10-02'
            ),
            array(
                'start_date' => '2014-10-03',
                'end_date' => ' 2014-10-04'
            ),
            array(
                'start_date' => '2014-10-06',
                'end_date' => ' 2014-10-23'
            ),
        array(
                'start_date' => '2014-11-19',
                'end_date' => '2014-11-23'
            ),
            array(
                'start_date' => '2014-11-25',
                'end_date' => ' 2014-11-28'
            )
);

$new_1 = array(
    array(
                'start_date' => '2014-10-03',
                'end_date' => ' 2014-10-04'
            ),
            array(
                'start_date' => '2014-10-10',
                'end_date' => ' 2014-10-12'
            ),
            array(
                'start_date' => '2014-10-17',
                'end_date' => '2014-10-19'
            ),
            array(
                'start_date' => '2014-11-19',
                'end_date' => ' 2014-11-23'
            ),
            array(
                'start_date' => '2014-11-25',
                'end_date' => '2014-11-28'
            )
);
```

I was comparing array $old_1 and array $new_1, looking for the dates are not in array $old_1. The result as I was expecting:

```
$expected_1 = array(
    array(
            array(
                'start_date' => '2014-10-10',
                'end_date' => ' 2014-10-12'
            ),
            array(
                'start_date' => '2014-10-17',
                'end_date' => '2014-10-19'
            )
);
```

I use this function to do it:

```
function checkDate($redDate, $date_range)
    {
        $start_object = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $redDate['start_date']);
        $end_object = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $redDate['end_date']);

        if (is_array($date_range)) {
            foreach ($date_range as $key => $row) {
                $range_start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row['start_date']);
                $range_end = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row['end_date']);

                if ($start_object != $range_start && $end_object != $range_end) {
                    if ($start_object < $range_end && $end_object > $range_start) {
                        $date = $redDate;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $date;
    }

$expected = array();
foreach ($new_1 as $dates) {
$value = checkDate($dates, $old_1);
if (!empty($value)) {
$expected[] = $value;
}
}
```

but that's function does not work with these two arrays:

```
$old_2 = array(
    array(
                'start_date' => '2014-09-26',
                'end_date' => '2014-09-28'
            ),
            array(
                'start_date' => '2014-10-03',
                'end_date' => ' 2014-10-04'
            )
);
$new_2 = array(
    array(
                'start_date' => '2014-09-26',
                'end_date' => '2014-09-28'
            ),
            array(
                'start_date' => '2014-10-03',
                'end_date' => ' 2014-10-04'
            ),
            array(
                'start_date' => '2014-10-17',
                'end_date' => '2014-10-20'
            ),
            array(
                'start_date' => '2014-10-29',
                'end_date' => ' 2015-01-02'
            )
);
```

I was expecting :

```
$expected_2 = array(
        array(
                array(
                    'start_date' => '2014-10-17',
                    'end_date' => '2014-10-20'
                ),
                array(
                    'start_date' => '2014-10-29',
                    'end_date' => ' 2015-01-02'
                )
    );
```

but I got empty array instead:

```
$result_2 = array(
    );
```

do I miss something in comparation function?
I need your advise guys, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `checkDate` function:

```
function checkDate($redDate, $date_range)
    {
        $start_object = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $redDate['start_date']);
        $end_object = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $redDate['end_date']);

        if (is_array($date_range)) {
            foreach ($date_range as $key => $row) {
                $range_start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row['start_date']);
                $range_end = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row['end_date']);

                // if the date was found return a null object
                if ($start_object == $range_start && $end_object == $range_end) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        // the date was not found so return the date
        return $redDate;
    }
```

Comment: hello,
yes, it works, now I got the result as I expected it.
There's new problem, in array $new_1, I got:
`array(
                'start_date' => '2014-10-10',
                'end_date' => ' 2014-10-12'
            ),
            array(
                'start_date' => '2014-10-17',
                'end_date' => '2014-10-19'
            )`
which is overlapping with the old value of $old_1 array:
`array(
                'start_date' => '2014-10-06',
                'end_date' => ' 2014-10-23'
            ),`
how to eliminate new array value when they have conflict with the old one?

Comment: so the correct for $expected_1 is an empty array() since 10-12 and 10-17 are eliminated because of overlapping.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are spaces in some of the dates of your examples. That's a mistake that you should correct.

Here you have the trace of the inner if.

```
2014-09-26 < 2014-10-04 TRUE && 2014-09-28 > 2014-10-03 FALSE
2014-10-03 < 2014-09-28 FALSE && 2014-10-04 > 2014-09-26 TRUE
2014-10-17 < 2014-09-28 FALSE && 2014-10-20 > 2014-09-26 TRUE
2014-10-17 < 2014-10-04 FALSE && 2014-10-20 > 2014-10-03 TRUE
2014-10-29 < 2014-09-28 FALSE && 2015-01-02 > 2014-09-26 TRUE
2014-10-29 < 2014-10-04 FALSE && 2015-01-02 > 2014-10-03 TRUE
array(0) { }
```

Anyway, I don't know exactly what your looking for. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm looking for a date range (start_date - end_date) in $new_1 array which are not in $old_1 array.
sorry I just don mention, The $old_1 array is fetched from database/table, and the $new_1 array is pulled from service. I want to insert new fetched data which are not in database/table into it.