# How to merge date range in array

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have some date ranges in array, and want to merge them. The result is a date range with the lowest start date and the highest end date. These are some samples in different cases.
case 1:

```
$case1 = array(
    array(
        'start_date' => '2014-10-06',
        'end_date' => '2014-10-23',
    ),
    array(
        'start_date' => '2014-10-10',
        'end_date' => '2014-10-12',
    ),
    array(
        'start_date' => '2014-10-17',
        'end_date' => '2014-10-19',
    ),
);

//expected
$res1 = array('start_date' => '2014-10-06', 'end_date' => '2014-10-23');
```

case 2:

```
$case2 = array(
    array(
        'start_date' => '2014-10-06',
        'end_date' => '2014-10-23',
    ),
    array(
        'start_date' => '2014-09-10',
        'end_date' => '2014-10-12',
    ),
    array(
        'start_date' => '2014-10-17',
        'end_date' => '2014-10-19',
    ),
);

//expected
$res2 = array('start_date' => '2014-09-10', 'end_date' => '2014-10-23');
```

case 3:

```
$case3 = array(
    array(
        'start_date' => '2014-10-06',
        'end_date' => '2014-10-23',
    ),
    array(
        'start_date' => '2014-10-10',
        'end_date' => '2014-10-12',
    ),
    array(
        'start_date' => '2014-10-17',
        'end_date' => '2014-11-12',
    ),
);

//expected
$res3 = array('start_date' => '2014-10-06', 'end_date' => '2014-11-12');
```

Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you guys

Comment: What have you tried?  Stack overflow is for helping people, not for doing it for them...

Comment: actually it's part of this question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076860/comparing-date-value-between-two-array` , I was stuck on it. thank you btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're just aiming at the lowest and highest date, just convert them to seconds, sort them then get the first and last:

```
$case1 = array(
    array(
        'start_date' => '2014-10-06',
        'end_date' => '2014-10-23',
    ),
    array(
        'start_date' => '2014-10-10',
        'end_date' => '2014-10-12',
    ),
    array(
        'start_date' => '2014-10-17',
        'end_date' => '2014-10-19',
    ),
);

$all_dates = array();
array_walk_recursive($case1, function($date) use (&$all_dates){ $all_dates[] = strtotime($date); }); // put them all inside and convert them to seconds
sort($all_dates); // normal sorting
$res1 = array('start_date' => date('Y-m-d', reset($all_dates)), 'end_date' => date('Y-m-d', end($all_dates))); // then assign the first element = start, and end element = end date
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the built-in php array functions:

`array_merge_recursive` or `array_replace_recursive`